# Can a witness at Kiddushin have had committed inconsequential crimes?

Tags: marriage, edim-witnesses, kiddushin-eirusin, moshe-feinstein, invalid-pasul

I remember hearing in the name of Rav Moshe Feinstein that a criminal who-- by normal and objective standards-- *should* be invalidated from testifying can still be considered a Kosher witness if his crime is not considered criminal as per subjective societal norms.

Where can I find this Teshuva?

Some extra clues: If I remember correctly, the witness in question had, or was going to testify at a Kiddushin. He had evaded taxes, smuggled or something similar in Europe and was now residing in the United States. Rav Moshe claimed that although a criminal by mid 1900s United States' standards, because what he had done was "*normal*" in Europe, his testimony was valid.

Obviously my memory can be, and probably is, incorrect in certain respects of the story/Teshuva. I was unable myself to locate any references online.

Comment: Where the Halacha said that every Avera makes someonee Pasul, the Mishna in Sanhedrin says אלו הן הפסולין for psulin derabanan and counts Gazlan, it seems that a lot of Averot don't make a problem about Edut